# Create repeated increasing sequence based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have col1 in a pandas df. I want to make col2:

```
col1    col2
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       2
2       3
2       4
3       3
3       4
4       4
```

In other words, for each distinct value in col1 I want col2 to be increasing integers that start with the value in col1 and counts up by one until there are no more rows.

The data is structured in a way so that max(col1) = 2450:

- when col1 = 1, there are 2450 rows
- when col1 = 2, there are 2449 rows
- when col1 = 2450, there is 1 row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) column `col1`, take the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) of the groups and [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) `col1`:

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount().add(df.col1)
```

**Output**

```
    col1  col2
0     1     1
1     1     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
4     2     2
5     2     3
6     2     4
7     3     3
8     3     4
9     4     4
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you!